# Why can't I cut off the volatile from spinlock implementation?

Tags: c#, volatile

According to this article,  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163715.aspx,
this is the implementation of spinlock class:

```
class SpinLock
        {
            volatile int isEntered;
            // non-zero if the lock is entered 
            public void Enter()
            {
                while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref isEntered, 1, 0) != 0)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(0); // force a thread context switch 
                }
            }
            public void Exit()
            {
                isEntered = 0;
            }
        }
```

I know what volatile means and does but I cant understand why its here.

Last thing I wanna ask in another topic- Does reading a object's property count as atomic operation? from my understanding, there are 2 reads here: first, the object reference and second the property reading.

Comment: Suppose `isEntered` weren't volatile - what's going to force the write from the thread calling `Exit` to be visible in other threads?

Comment: Thank you for your comment but Im not sure I got what you are tring to say.

Comment: Well look at what `volatile` means - the full definition - and see how that changes the behaviour of `Exit`. If you think it doesn't affect it at all, that suggests that you don't really know what volatile means after all, and need to do some more research.

Comment: Please note that this is "A simple spin lock", it's not the implementation of `System.Threading.SpinLock`.

Comment: for your first quastion, the answer has nothing to do with volatile. other threads will keep try to exit the while loop as normal and when the thread who owns the lock will call exit, will change the 'IsEntered' to 0 and aother thread will leave the while loop.

Comment: If you have two questions please post two separate questions.

Comment: I am confused by the first question. You say you understand what volatile does, then you ask why it is necessary, which strongly indicates that you do not know what it does. Your question is therefore please explain why my understanding of volatile is wrong. But we don't know what false beliefs you hold unless you tell us!

Comment: To answer jons question correctly, actually make a pencil and paper model of a weak memory model architecture and simulate some possible races and you will quickly see why volatile is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

After (re)studying memory models for a couple of days, I had the same vexing question about the use of `volatile` in SpinLock. I cannot find any problematic reordering of memory access that requires either of the fences entailed by the volatile access.

- Acquire fence: Provided by `Interlocked.CompareExchange()`.
- Release fence: To get lock semantics, we want all side effects of the code "under the lock" to be visible when the lock is released. But the .NET memory model does not permit reordering of writes. Therefore, the writes from under the lock must become visible no later than the clearing of `isEntered`.

**Update**
After some more study based on the Core CLR discussions, I figured out where the disconnect is. First, the two popular sources that state writes also include a release fence or just that they cannot be reordered:

- http://joeduffyblog.com/2007/11/10/clr-20-memory-model/

  > Rule 2: All stores have release semantics, i.e. no load or store may move after one.
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2005/october/understanding-low-lock-techniques-in-multithreaded-apps, in the "Strong Model 2: .NET Framework 2.0" section:

  > Writes cannot move past other writes from the same thread.

Turns out that the ".NET Framework 2 model" is not inherited by all later versions and ports of the framework. The most enlightening article ended up being this one: [C# - The C# Memory Model in Theory and Practice, Part 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/january/csharp-the-csharp-memory-model-in-theory-and-practice-part-2). The author explains the more relaxed CLR implementations for IA64 and ARM. Essentially, normal writes can be reordered, and thus memory fences are needed in some situations. (How they've decided to insert a release fence before a normal write to a reference type field on the heap strikes me as a desperate hack for maintaining compatibility with code written for x86, but it's well justified in the historical context and the context of the popular lock-free object publication pattern.)

**Conclusion**: `volatile` is needed for the SpinLock field in a generic ".NET" implementation to ensure writes under the lock occur before the lock is released--without taking dependence on the stronger ".NET Framework 2 model" or the CPU architecture.

Comment: *"the .NET memory model does not permit reordering of writes"* -- Could you link to the source of this info?

Comment: * http://joeduffyblog.com/2007/11/10/clr-20-memory-model/ <br/>
* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2005/october/understanding-low-lock-techniques-in-multithreaded-apps:
  <q>Writes cannot move past other writes from the same thread.</q>

Answer (score 0):

After reading a few sources, I had the impression that volatile only affects reordering done by compiler/runtime during optimization. The C# 5.0 Reference indicates it's more than this:

> These optimizations can be performed by the compiler, by the run-time system, **or by hardware**

And then I came across this little article
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31283/Volatile-fields-in-NET-A-look-inside